# 'childNodes' of undefined al recorrer XML con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Al momento de hacer una petición Ajax, la respuesta que obtengo es un XML como el siguiente:

```
<wp_ajax>
    <response action="add-tag_0">
        <taxonomy id="0" position="1">
            <response_data/>
            <supplemental>
                <parents></parents>
                <noparents/>
            </supplemental>
        </taxonomy>
    </response>
    <response action="add-tag_0">
        <term id="0" position="0">
            <response_data/>
            <supplemental>
                <term_id>514</term_id>
                <name>Juan Lopez</name>
                <slug>juan-lopez</slug>
                <term_group>0</term_group>
                <term_taxonomy_id>514</term_taxonomy_id>
                <taxonomy>booked_custom_calendars</taxonomy>
                <description><p>juan@lopez.co</p></description>
                <parent>0</parent>
                <count>0</count>
                <filter>display</filter>
            </supplemental>
        </term>
    </response>
</wp_ajax>
```

Lo recorro de la siguiente manera:

```
jQuery(xml).find('response').each(function(i) {
    var term_id = ((xml.getElementsByTagName('term_id')[i]).childNodes[0]).nodeValue;
    jQuery('#esb_subfield_cus_field_calendario').val('[booked-calendar calendar='+ term_id +']');
});
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error: `Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`

De tantas formas que encontré de recorrer el XML esta fue la que me funciono pero me arroja el error y todo el JS que sigue después no se ejecuta. Cabe aclarar que el Script se ejecuta y realiza la función pero, como les digo saca el error  y todo el JS que sigue después no se ejecuta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es un simple problema de validación.

Estas iterando la cantidad de veces que exista el elemento `response`, es decir, en el **XML** de tu ejemplo iterarías dos veces teniendo los índices `0` y `1`, pero al tratar de capturar el elemento `term_id` en el índice `0` dicho elemento no existe, es por esto que te saca el error.

La solución es simple, antes de capturar el valor del elemento `term_id` debes validar que efectivamente exista.

En el ejemplo hice un `parseo` para que pudiera funcionar, ignora esos ajustes.

```js
var xml = '<wp_ajax>\
    <response action="add-tag_0">\
        <taxonomy id="0" position="1">\
            <response_data/>\
            <supplemental>\
                <parents></parents>\
                <noparents/>\
            </supplemental>\
        </taxonomy>\
    </response>\
    <response action="add-tag_0">\
        <term id="0" position="0">\
            <response_data/>\
            <supplemental>\
                <term_id>514</term_id>\
                <name>Juan Lopez</name>\
                <slug>juan-lopez</slug>\
                <term_group>0</term_group>\
                <term_taxonomy_id>514</term_taxonomy_id>\
                <taxonomy>booked_custom_calendars</taxonomy>\
                <description><p>juan@lopez.co</p></description>\
                <parent>0</parent>\
                <count>0</count>\
                <filter>display</filter>\
            </supplemental>\
        </term>\
    </response>\
</wp_ajax>';

parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

jQuery(xmlDoc).find('response').each(function(i) {
  if(((xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('term_id')[i])) != undefined){
    var term_id = ((xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('term_id')[i]).childNodes[0]).nodeValue;
    jQuery('#esb_subfield_cus_field_calendario').val('[booked-calendar calendar='+ term_id +']');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="esb_subfield_cus_field_calendario" />
```

Comment: Camilooooo! bienvenido de vuelta :D

Comment: @fredyfx amigo mio!! :D ya voy al chat!

Comment: Gracias. No me sale el error, pero ahora esta parte no se cumple: jQuery('#esb_subfield_cus_field_calendario').val('[booked-calendar calendar='+ term_id +']');

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea y lo tienes dentro del if de la validación? que sucede ahora?

Comment: Si, está dentro del if pero no hace nada. Tengo lo mismo que hiciste de ejemplo y no imprime nada, pero el error dejo de salir y el resto del código se ejecuta.

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea acabo de editar mi ejemplo con la funcionalidad que se supone debes tener, y funciona, así que supongo que debes tener algo diferente en tu código, revísalo bien y me cuentas